# The fewest questions should be prepared for a exam

Tags: combinatorics

$N$ students will do a test paper with $M$ question and for a consideration of cheat, every paper will be different, but not totally. There are at most $K$ questions same in any two papers. Given the $N$, $M$ and $K$, $I$ want to know the fewest questions should be prepared.

Example:

> $N = 3\qquad  3~ \text{students} \\
>  M = 2 \qquad 2 ~\text{questions} \\
>  K = 1  \qquad \text{at most 1 question is same}$

Answer: $3$ (let the $3$ questions be `ABC` and then first student's paper is `AB`, the second is `BC` and the third is `AC`)

Another Example:

> $N = 12\qquad M = 3\qquad K = 1$

Answer: $9$

```
111000000 -> means first student's paper is `ABC`
100110000 -> means second student's paper is `ADE`
010101000
001100100
000011100
010010010
001001010
100000110
001010001
100001001
010000101
000100011
```

The matrix is of $12 \times 9$, means $9$ questions is sufficient for $12$ paper with $3$ questions and at most $1$ same question pairwise.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but, for the subcase K=M-1, the answer is K+N-1

Comment: The easier case of K=0 has $N \times M$ questions :)

Comment: @Sayakiss : As another example, if N=4 : AB, BC, AC, CD -- hence 4 questions?

Comment: @gar you mean K is 1? I think you are right. Since 3 questions don't match the need and the answer is 4 with no doubt..

Comment: @gar I add another strong case.

Comment: @Sayakiss : Okay, saw it, thanks.

Comment: Looks like it is equivalent to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_bound.

Comment: @user21820 it's similiar, not equivalent. The crucial part is the code can be repeatedly but a question cannot appear two times in a test pepar...

Comment: Oh sorry I was wrong, but it's not what you said actually. A binary code with code length $n$ and hamming distance $d$ will guarantee that any two code words differ by at lease $d$ bits. So if we further constrain the code such that each code word must have exactly $m$ "1"s, then it is indeed equivalent to your question if $d = 2(m-k)$.

Comment: @user21820 You're right, but I think it's harder with constraint `must have exactly m "1"s` than the original' problem....

Comment: Sorry I meant code length $x$ where $x$ is the number of questions. Well at least an upper bound on the number of code words in a normal hamming code will be an upper bound on the number of code words with that additional constraint, so by inverting that you get a lower bound on $x$ given the desired number of tests. But I'm not familiar with coding theory so I can't really help.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the classical problems in Extremal Set Theory, and there is no simple combinatorial solution, which I guess you are hoping for. [This](http://www.mathematik.uni-bielefeld.de/ahlswede/homepage/public/122.pdf) paper will shed some light on its complexity.

Comment: What is the name of that problem in Extremal Set Theory?

Comment: Its a generalised version of the Erdos-Ko-Rado theorem. The attached paper has the (nearly) latest results.

Comment: But Erdos-Ko-Rado theorem is about r-size set pairwise intersects, is a little bit different my problem..

Comment: @Sayakiss In order to minimize the total number of questions you need to maximize their occurrence, so your statement about "atmost $k$ questions common" becomes "exactly $k$ questions common" in this extremal setting. This is what the generalized version of Erdos-Ko-Rado theorem addresses.

Comment: Not exactly. `exactly k questions common` cannot be achieved in some cases but it's still a optimal solution. In my second example, the solution is optimal but not every set intersects...

Comment: Ofcourse for all $n$ not all set will have $k$ elements common. But it will happen for some $n$'s. Your,s example ie. $n=12$ might not be one of those values.

Comment: It's not true, n = 13 need more than 9 questions according to my program..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15821/discussion-between-uma-kant-and-sayakiss).